# Updating app database daily through internet connection

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, server

I would like to know what are my options and what are the best practices for apps that update themeselves regurarly though internet connection. 
Example app: Livescore app which updates itself with the latest match results.

What are the best "free" ways to do this? (a server might cost me money for this?).
So far I found a tutorial which uses google sheets. Do you recommend it?

My app is going to update itself once a day.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See this: https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html

Comment: Thank you, I'll take a look at it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase. Upgrading is not necessary, unless you're looking for some special features / capacity. Pubnub. Great for real-time data transfer. Free version is up to 1M messages. I would search online for other services as well, if I were you.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I had exams.

DIdin't know that Firebase had these features and I had never heard about Pubnub. I will take a look at them and decide which one to use. 
Thanks for the help :)

Comment: PubNub will have a blog about this coming out soon. Stay tuned for details here.

Comment: Part 1 of 3: https://www.pubnub.com/blog/2016-09-01-diy-virtual-white-board-using-google-and-firebase/